# Unable to find element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written below code to select the radio button and it was working fine but today its not working.Please find the code and corresponding error message

Code1:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    WebElement radio = wait.until    (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("0_2485A_StartDate")));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio);
```

Error1:
'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: 0_2485A_StartDate'

Code2:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        WebElement radio = wait.until    (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Radio_0_2485A")));
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio);
```

Error2:
'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: Radio_0_2485A'

Code3:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("0_2485A_StartDate")));
        radio.click();
```

Error3:
'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: 0_2485A_StartDate'

Code4:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Radio_0_2485A")));
        radio.click();

Error4:
'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: Radio_0_2485A'

HTML:

```
    <th class="radio">
    <input id="0_2485A_StartDate" type="hidden" value="18/12/2015 00:01:00">

    <input name="Products[0].ProductCode" title="5 Year Fixed Rate Until 28/02/2021 with £999 Fee" id="Radio_0_2485A" type="radio" value="2485A">
    <label for="Radio_0_2485A">
       5 Year Fixed Rate Until 28/02/2021 with £999 Fee
  </label>
    </th>
```

Please do suggest.

Comment: No its not dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`presenceOfElementLocated` just checking the element existing in the `DOM`, So if you are using this with `ExpectedConditions` your code would work fine.

But as I'm seeing, exception stacktrace states you're using `elementToBeClickable`, Actually `elementToBeClickable` is used to wait until element visible and clickable while located element is hidden and it would never be visible.

You're locating hidden element that's why you're in trouble.

You should try to locate actual radio element as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Radio_0_2485A")))
radio.click()
```

Comment: When I tried with below code WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
  WebElement radio = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("0_2485A_StartDate")));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio);

Comment: I have already told you you are locating hidden element using elementToBeClickable, you should try with this I'd `0_2485A_StartDate` which is visible and actual I'd of radio element

Comment: Saurabh...I think code3 is what you are referring to.Please have a look on code3.I am getting error when I am using code3 as well..

Comment: Saurabh...how can I check whether the element is inside the fram?and my friend is also using same code(code1) and its working in his machine...

Comment: If same code with same elements works on different machine then probably it's not inside and frame/iframe, any to check existence of frame/frame just go to browser console by pressing f12 at that page and execute this `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")` and `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")` and check if results found with frame.

Comment: Saurabh...As you said its not inside frame and its not dynamically changing.

Comment: Than are you sure it is visible on the screen??

Comment: @LakshmiD If it's visible on the screen and it's not inside in the frame/iframe and also I'd is not changeable the I don't think what could be the reason..may it's timing issue. You should increase the timeout limit from 10 to more, may be then it works..

Answer (score 0):

I had no way to replicate your actual web browser scenario, but just tried to copy your html code and put in a simple html template. I saw that you tried almost everything.. if possible can you give the url where others can look into the page.

I tried like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='2485A']")).click();
```

and it worked. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sandipan...I tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='2485A']")).click();
 and its not working...

Comment: Can you give the url, so that we all can check in our machines